# Send SMS with fake number

Tags: java, android

Recently I've gotten into Android app development, and I was wondering if it was possible to send out a text message that will say it came from a randomly generated number?
Thanks.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately this is not possible because it will introduce lots of spam.

But you can use this method to send an SMS with your program.

```
private void sendSms(String phonenumber,String message, boolean isBinary)
{
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

    if(isBinary)
    {
            byte[] data = new byte[message.length()];

            for(int index=0; index<message.length() && index < MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH; ++index)
            {
                    data[index] = (byte)message.charAt(index);
            }

            manager.sendDataMessage(phonenumber, null, (short) SMS_PORT, data,piSend, piDelivered);
    }
    else
    {
            int length = message.length();

            if(length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
            {
                    ArrayList<String> messagelist = manager.divideMessage(message);

                    manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null, messagelist, null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                    manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, piSend, piDelivered);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately? u sure?

Comment: Yes, if this was possible I would be able to text anyone, and have it come from random number. You can always use an API such as Twilio and have them send messages for you using one of their provided numbers, but you have to pay.

Comment: LOL, note my comment "Unfortunately? or fortunately!"

Comment: Edit made to original post.